# How to run command in PC before Android Instumented tests are executed

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I am testing code with Android's awesome instrumented tests. I want to test socket related stuff, and I wrote a test server in Python to help me test my sockets.

**While running "normal" unit tests** (which are run in locally in PC), there is no problem to do this:

```
@Before
public void setUp throws Exception {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python socket_server.py");
}
```

And then after test case I naturally close the server.

However, when I run Instrumented Tests, **test server tries to run in Android device**, which apparently does not work.

My question is, **how do I start test server programatically before my instrumented tests are run?**

Thanks in advance!